# Why XCode 4.0 Compiler Doesn't Report Line Numbers On Errors?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc, objective-c++, llvm-gcc

So, I'm trying to create a cross platform project by having a projects directory for my multiple platforms and a source directory where I will be keeping all of my source files used by the multiple projects.

Something that just came up with XCode is I try to reference a file outside of the XCode projects directory path, a folder path connected by a parent folder, then if there is a compiler error, XCode does not more the specific lines that have an error. Instead, when I clicked the error in the Issue Navigator, it opens the file at the top and the file is devoid of any marks.

Does anyone have any idea how to get XCode to mark up these files properly even though the file is not under the same directory path of the project or workspace?

I know this might seem a little strange or convoluted. I will try and answer any questions about my problem as best as I can.

Answer (score 1):

A work-around is to simply click on the issue in the log navigator. In the log navigator, you get the direct compiler output including line numbers.

It's still very annoying, since issue navigator even fails for many template c++ classes within the project.